# Can I run a rake task inside a generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I have a simple rails install generator for an engine I'm making:

```
module Bouncer
  module Generators
    class InstallGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
      source_root File.expand_path("../../templates", __FILE__)

      desc "Copies locale file and migrations to your application."

      def copy_locale
        copy_file "../../../config/locales/en.yml", "config/locales/bouncer.en.yml"
      end

      def copy_migrations
        # I would like to run "rake bouncer_engine:install:migrations" right here
        # rather than copy_file "../../../db/migrate/blah.rb", "db/migrate/blah.rb"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When a user runs `rails g bouncer:install`, a locale file is copied into their app. I also want to copy in my migrations, but rather than use `copy_file` method, I was hoping I could just run `rake bouncer_engine:install:migrations` inside the generator, like I would do from the command line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env rake
module Bouncer
  module Generators
    class InstallGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
      desc "Copies migrations to your application."
      def copy_migrations
        rake("bouncer_engine:install:migrations")
      end    
    end
  end
end
```

This saves a lot of hassle and even takes care of the making sure each migration's name is timestamped properly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think it should be possible by just executing the shell command. [Here](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html) are 6 different ways to execute a shell command in ruby.

But my other suggestion would be instead of implementing it as a rake task, to direcly implement it as part of your generator... I don't know what your exact demands are, but given your description it seems to me that the migrations-task only runs once, when you execute the install task? Or is there a special need to offer it as a rake task as well?

Comment: yeah, I am trying to make it run as part of the install task, I take it you can't just run a rake task inside a generator then?

Comment: Not directly by re-using your code, as far as I know. But running the rake command as a shell command from your code should work... you just have to make sure to execute it in the right directory

Comment: ahh, thanks for your info. I was tring to use `        Rake::Task['rake bouncer_engine:install:migrations'].execute` from inside my generator but now I'm just going to do what you say and copy  the files over using [this technique](http://www.dixis.com/?p=444)

Comment: Actually, I've added an answer which shows how to do this. I borrowed the technique from refinerycms. Thanks for your help anyway,

Comment: Ah... good! I didn't know this :) But you should mark it as answered.